# Cómo mostrar inputs dependiendo del valor de select option

Tags: javascript, html

muy buenas a todos.

Estoy haciendo un formulario y con ello quiero agregar prefijos a un `<input type="tel">`.

El caso es que por cada una de las opciones necesito un input con `pattern` distinto y añadiendo el `required`.

**HTML y JS**

```js
function showInp(){
  getSelectValue = document.getElementById("telprefix").value;
  if(select.salue==and){
    docuement.getElementById("andphone").style.display = "inline-block";
  }
   if(select.value==esp){
    docuement.getElementById("espphone").style.display = "inline-block";
  }
  
   if(select.value==fr){
    docuement.getElementById("frphone").style.display = "inline-block";
  }
}

if( document.getElementById("telprefix").value === "and"){
  docuement.getElementById("andphone").addAttribute("required");
  
}

if( document.getElementById("telprefix").value === "esp"){
  docuement.getElementById("espphone").addAttribute("required");
  
}

if( document.getElementById("telprefix").value === "fr"){
  docuement.getElementById("frphone").addAttribute("required");
  
}
```

```html
<select name="telprefix" id="telprefix" onchange="showInp()">
    <option value="">--Prefix</option>
    <option value="and">+376</option>
    <option value="esp">+34</option>
    <option value="fr">+33</option>
    
  </select>
  
  <input id="andphone" type="tel" pattern="[3]{9}-[3]{9}" style="display: none"/>
  <input id="espphone" type="tel" pattern="[3]{9}-[3]{9}-[3]{9}" style="display: none"/>
  <input id="frphone" type="tel"  pattern="[1]{9}[3]{9}-[3]{9}-[3]{9}" style="display: none"/>
```

Obviamente no funciona porque no tengo ni idea de JavaScript.
Si me podéis ayudar y explicar un poco cómo se hace sería de gran ayuda.

Muchas gracias de antemano,

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Veo varios errores en tu código, principalmente de escribir mal una palabra, ten mucho cuidado con eso porque son errores que puedes arrastrar todo el código y luego no sabes qué es lo que falla.

El primer error es que estás creando la variable `getSelectValue`, sin embargo luego intentas utilizarla llamándola `select`. Además, en la variable almacenas el valor del `value` y luego intentas coger de nuevo el `value` de eso. Es decir, recoges el `value` obtienes el valor "and" e intentas coger el `value` de un string.

También comparas el string obtenido con variables que no existen. Si quieres saber si el valor obtenido es "and" debes compararlo con un string `"and"` y no con una variable `and` que no existe.

```
function showInp(){
  var getSelectValue = document.getElementById("telprefix").value;
  if(getSelectValue == "and"){
    docuement.getElementById("andphone").style.display = "inline-block";
  }
   if(getSelectValue == "esp"){
    docuement.getElementById("espphone").style.display = "inline-block";
  }

   if(getSelectValue == "fr"){
    docuement.getElementById("frphone").style.display = "inline-block";
  }
}
```

Además, durante todo el código está el error en que has escrito `docuement`, debería ser `document`. Al haber copiado y pegado una línea con este error, lo has arrastrado en el resto del código.

Así quedaría tu código funcionando, la teoría la has sabido poner en práctica, han sido errores al escribirlo:

```js
function showInp(){
  var getSelectValue = document.getElementById("telprefix").value;

  if(getSelectValue=="and"){
    document.getElementById("andphone").style.display = "inline-block";
  }
   if(getSelectValue=="esp"){
    document.getElementById("espphone").style.display = "inline-block";
  }
  
   if(getSelectValue=="fr"){
    document.getElementById("frphone").style.display = "inline-block";
  }
}

if( document.getElementById("telprefix").value === "and"){
  document.getElementById("andphone").addAttribute("required");
  
}

if( document.getElementById("telprefix").value === "esp"){
  document.getElementById("espphone").addAttribute("required");
  
}

if( document.getElementById("telprefix").value === "fr"){
  document.getElementById("frphone").addAttribute("required");
  
}
```

```html
<select name="telprefix" id="telprefix" onchange="showInp()">
    <option value="">--Prefix</option>
    <option value="and">+376</option>
    <option value="esp">+34</option>
    <option value="fr">+33</option>
    
  </select>
  
  <input id="andphone" type="tel" pattern="[3]{9}-[3]{9}" style="display: none"/>
  <input id="espphone" type="tel" pattern="[3]{9}-[3]{9}-[3]{9}" style="display: none"/>
  <input id="frphone" type="tel"  pattern="[1]{9}[3]{9}-[3]{9}-[3]{9}" style="display: none"/>
```

Ten en cuenta que el código fuera de la función nunca se ejecuta, es decir, los `input` nunca son `required`. Para ello deberías meter este código en la función.

Y sobre ocultar los `inputs` que no se utilizan, al ponerlo en `inline-block` sustituyes el que tienes en html por ese, por lo que deberías volver a decírselo.

Para que el código sea más limpio, lo he hecho todo en `switch` ya que creo que te podrá ayudar a mantenerlo en el futuro:

```js
function showInp(){
  var getSelectValue = document.getElementById("telprefix").value;
  
  switch (getSelectValue) {
    case "and": 
      document.getElementById("andphone").style.display = "inline-block";
      document.getElementById("andphone").setAttribute("required", "required");
      document.getElementById("espphone").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("frphone").style.display = "none";
      break;
      
    case "esp":
      document.getElementById("espphone").style.display = "inline-block";
      document.getElementById("espphone").setAttribute("required", "required");
      document.getElementById("andphone").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("frphone").style.display = "none";
      break;
      
    case "fr":
      document.getElementById("frphone").style.display = "inline-block";
      document.getElementById("frphone").setAttribute("required", "required");
      document.getElementById("espphone").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("andphone").style.display = "none";
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="telprefix" id="telprefix" onchange="showInp()">
    <option value="">--Prefix</option>
    <option value="and">+376</option>
    <option value="esp">+34</option>
    <option value="fr">+33</option>
    
  </select>
  
  <input id="andphone" type="tel" pattern="[3]{9}-[3]{9}" style="display: none"/>
  <input id="espphone" type="tel" pattern="[3]{9}-[3]{9}-[3]{9}" style="display: none"/>
  <input id="frphone" type="tel"  pattern="[1]{9}[3]{9}-[3]{9}-[3]{9}" style="display: none"/>
```

Comment: Qué cabeza la mía... Ahora la cosa está en que se siguen mostrando aunque cambies de prefijo. Cómo hago para que el js no predomine en el display y quede lo que le he puesto en el html?

Comment: Ya está editado y añadido eso :)

Comment: Estupendo, muchísimas gracias ^^

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que te diria es que revises tu codigo. Tienes muchisimos errores como `docuement` en lugar de `document` etc...

Respecto a tu pregunta, si obtienes el valor del `select`, es de tipo `String` (texto) y tienes que compararlo en el `if` con un valor igual.

Por otro lado, te recomiendo que ocultes los otros `input` cuando muestras uno nuevo. Puedes hacerlo en los `if` de uno en uno, o ocultarlos todos según llames a la función `showinput` y luego mostrar el necesario.

```js
function showInp(){
  getSelectValue = document.getElementById("telprefix").value;
  if(getSelectValue=="and"){
    document.getElementById("andphone").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("espphone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("frphone").style.display = "none";
  }else if(getSelectValue=="esp"){
    document.getElementById("andphone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("espphone").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("frphone").style.display = "none";
  }else if(getSelectValue=="fr"){
    document.getElementById("andphone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("espphone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("frphone").style.display = "inline-block";
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="telprefix" id="telprefix" onchange="showInp()">
    <option value="">--Prefix</option>
    <option value="and">+376</option>
    <option value="esp">+34</option>
    <option value="fr">+33</option> 
</select>

<input id="andphone" type="tel" pattern="[3]{9}-[3]{9}" style="display: none" placeholder="and"/>
<input id="espphone" type="tel" pattern="[3]{9}-[3]{9}-[3]{9}" style="display: none" placeholder="esp"/>
<input id="frphone" type="tel"  pattern="[1]{9}[3]{9}-[3]{9}-[3]{9}" style="display: none" placeholder="fr"/>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Sí, los que tocamos código no nos sienta bien la dislexia hahah. Gracias por responder y aportar la solución.